# Dicas para página de planos e como corrigir erro: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia pessoal!
Estou tentando fazer uma página de planos:
https://codepen.io/jkarlos96/pen/KRjrKV

- **Só que estou tendo problemas com o efeito do scroll.**
  Vocês podem ver que somente com os planos de clube ele funciona e os outros não funciona.
  **De acordo com o navegador está causando esse erro: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined**
- **Além disso eu queria ele voltasse ao topo** de acordo quando clica no botão mas, ele somente desce ele não sobe.

**Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor ?**

- *Se alguém também tiver alguma dica pra mim economizar linhas no código dos botões das categorias, essa foi a única forma que eu conseguir fazer funcionar.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não precisa usar vários `id`s para alterar elementos semelhantes, Assim você fica refém de ter que criar vários métodos para cada `id`, tornando seu trabalho mais complicado de manter e infla demais o código.

Para elementos semelhantes, procure usar classes, porque assim você consegue pegar os elementos pelo *index* (índice). Veja no exemplo abaixo com o código otimizado em que os cliques e os métodos são feitos de forma independente de `id`s, evitando repetições e deixando o código bem mais enxuto:

```js
//Botões de Categoria
$('.buttonDefault').click(function() {
   
   var bt = $(this);
   var idx = bt.index();

   $('.buttonDefault').removeClass("buttonActive buttonFamiliaActive planActive buttonClubActive");
   $('.plans').removeClass("planActive");
   bt.addClass("buttonClubActive buttonActive");
   $(".plans:eq("+idx+")").addClass("planActive");

});

//Botão "Ver Mais" para expandir a caixa com as informações dos planos
$('.verMais').click(function() {

   var bt = $(this);
   var idx = bt.closest(".priceColuna").index(".priceColuna");
   var lista = $(".list:eq("+idx+")");
   var winHeight = window.innerHeight/2;
   var altIni = 240;
   
   if(bt.hasClass("verMaisActive")){
      var tlista = altIni;
   }else{
      var thislista = $("li", lista);
      var tlista = 0;
      for(var x=0; x<thislista.length; x++){
         tlista += $(thislista[x]).outerHeight();
      }
   }

   bt.toggleClass("verMaisActive");
   lista.css("height", tlista+"px");

   var flag = false;
   lista.on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(e){
      
      if(!flag){
         flag = true;
         
         if(tlista == altIni){
            var scrolTo = $(".priceColuna");
            var scrolAdj = -15;
         }else{
            var scrolTo = $(".buttonComprar");
            var scrolAdj = -winHeight;
         }

         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop:
               scrolTo.eq(idx).offset().top + scrolAdj
         }, 800);
      }
   });

});
```

```css
.price{
 padding: 150px 15px;
}

.price h2{
 text-align: center;
}

.price h2 b{
 color: #94a4cf;
}

/*Botões de escolha de categoria ==========================================================*/
.priceButtons{
 height: 160px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.buttonClub, .buttonEscola, .buttonInvestidor, .buttonFamilia{
 width: 200px;
 height: 50px;
 background: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 1em;
 padding-top: 10px;
 border-top: 2px solid #252833;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #252833;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 700;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.buttonClub{
 border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
 border: 2px solid #252833;
}

.buttonFamilia{
 border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
 border: 2px solid #252833;
}

.buttonEscola{
 border-right:2px solid #252833;
}

/* .buttonClub:hover, .buttonEscola:hover, .buttonInvestidor:hover, .buttonFamilia:hover, .buttonActive{ */
.buttonDefault:hover, .buttonActive{
 background: #e8c29c;
 border-top-color: #D2AA82;
 border-bottom-color: #D2AA82;
}

.buttonClub:hover, .buttonClubActive{
 border-left-color: #D2AA82;
}

.buttonFamilia:hover, .buttonFamiliaActive{
 border-right-color: #D2AA82;
}

/*Colunas com os planos ==================================================================*/
.planClub, .planEscola, .planInvestidor, .planFamilia{
 display: none;
}

.planActive{
 display: block;
 animation: planos 0.3s;
 animation-fill-mode: both;
 -webkit-animation: planos 0.3s;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
 -moz-animation: planos 0.3s;
 -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
 -o-animation: planos 0.3s;
 -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes planos{
 from{opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
 to{opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes planos{
 from{opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
 to{opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
}
@-moz-keyframes planos{
 from{opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
 to{opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
}
@-o-keyframes planos{
 from{opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
 to{opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
}

/*Coluna de planos*/
.priceColuna{
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid #969696;
 border-radius: 10px;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

/*Nome dos planos*/
.priceName{
 background: #252833;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 30px 15px;
 color: #fff;
 
}

.priceName h5{
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.priceName p{
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 margin:0 auto;
}


/*Preço dos planos*/
.priceCusto{
 height: 70px;
 color: #D2AA82;
 background: #F4F4F4;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #969696;
}

.priceCusto h3{
 margin:0;
}

.priceCusto h3 b{
 font-size: 0.6666666666666666em;
 color: #969696;
 font-weight: 300;
}

/*Informações dos planos*/
.priceInfos{
 padding: 5px 20px;
}

.priceInfos ul{
 height: 240px;
 overflow: hidden;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin:0;
 transition: all 1s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease;
}

.priceInfos ul li{
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px 0;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #969696;
 font-size: 0.875em;
}

/*Botão comprar*/
.buttonComprar{
 width:150px;
 background: #D2AA82;
 border: 2px solid #a68667;
 border-radius: 50px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 1.125em;
 font-weight: 700;
 margin:0 auto;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
 -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
 -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
}

.priceColuna a{
 text-decoration: none;
}

.buttonComprar:hover{
 border: 2px solid #8997bf;
 background: #a7b9e9;
}

/*Botão ver mais*/
.verMais{
 margin:0 auto;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 background: #F4F4F4;

 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: 1px solid #969696;
}
.verMais::after{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 content: '';
 border-right: 4px solid transparent;
 border-left: 4px solid transparent;
 border-top: 5px solid #303543;
}

.verMaisActive::after{
 border-top: none !important;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #303543;
}

.listActiveClub{
 height: 680px !important;
}

.listActiveEscola{
 height: 804px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section class="container price">
  <h2>Como <b>cobramos</b> por nossos serviços</h2>
    
    <!-- Botões de Categorias-->
    <div class="priceButtons">
   <div class="buttonClub buttonDefault buttonActive buttonClubActive">Clubes</div>
   <div class="buttonEscola buttonDefault">Escolas</div>
   <div class="buttonInvestidor buttonDefault">Investidores</div>
   <div class="buttonFamilia buttonDefault">Familia</div>
  </div>

  <!--planos do clube-->
  <div class="planClub plans planActive">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="priceColuna">
      <!--nome-->
      <div class="priceName">
       <h5>Clubes</h5>
       <p>clubes</p>
      </div>
      <!--preço-->
      <div class="priceCusto">
       <h3>R$480<b> / mês</b></h3>
      </div>
      <!--informações-->
      <div class="priceInfos">
       <ul class="list">
        <li>CONTEUDO1</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
        <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDOfim</li>
       </ul>
       <div class="verMais"></div>
       <a href=""><div class="buttonComprar">Adquirir</div></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div><!--coluna-->

    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="priceColuna">
      <!--nome-->
      <div class="priceName">
       <h5>Clubes</h5>
       <p>clubes</p>
      </div>
      <!--preço-->
      <div class="priceCusto">
       <h3>R$480<b> / mês</b></h3>
      </div>
      <!--informações-->
      <div class="priceInfos">
       <ul class="list">
        <li>CONTEUDO1</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
        <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDOfim</li>
       </ul>
       <div class="verMais"></div>
       <a href=""><div class="buttonComprar">Adquirir</div></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div><!--coluna-->

    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="priceColuna">
      <!--nome-->
      <div class="priceName">
       <h5>Clubes</h5>
       <p>clubes</p>
      </div>
      <!--preço-->
      <div class="priceCusto">
       <h3>R$480<b> / mês</b></h3>
      </div>
      <!--informações-->
      <div class="priceInfos">
       <ul class="list">
        <li>CONTEUDO1</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
        <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDOfim</li>
       </ul>
       <div class="verMais"></div>
       <a href=""><div class="buttonComprar">Adquirir</div></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div><!--coluna-->
   </div><!--row-->
  </div><!--planos do clube-->

  
    
    <!--planos de escola-->
  <div class="planEscola plans">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="priceColuna">
      <!--nome-->
      <div class="priceName">
       <h5>Escola</h5>
       <p>Escola</p>
      </div>
      <!--preço-->
      <div class="priceCusto">
       <h3>R$300<b> / mês</b></h3>
      </div>
      <!--informações-->

      <div class="priceInfos">
       <ul class="list">
        <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
        <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
       </ul>
       <div class="verMais"></div>
       <a href=""><div class="buttonComprar">Adquirir</div></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div><!--coluna-->

    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="priceColuna">
      <!--nome-->
      <div class="priceName">
       <h5>Escola</h5>
       <p>Escola</p>
      </div>
      <!--preço-->
      <div class="priceCusto">
       <h3>R$300<b> / mês</b></h3>
      </div>
      <!--informações-->
      <div class="priceInfos">
       <ul class="list">
        <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
        <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
       </ul>
       <div class="verMais"></div>
       <a href=""><div class="buttonComprar">Adquirir</div></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div><!--coluna-->

    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="priceColuna">
      <!--nome-->
      <div class="priceName">
       <h5>Escola</h5>
       <p>Escola</p>
      </div>
      <!--preço-->
      <div class="priceCusto">
       <h3>R$300<b> / mês</b></h3>
      </div>
      <!--informações-->
      <div class="priceInfos">
       <ul class="list">
        <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
        <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
                <li>CONTEUDO</li>
       </ul>
       <div class="verMais"></div>
       <a href=""><div class="buttonComprar">Adquirir</div></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div><!--coluna-->
   </div><!--row-->
  </div><!--planos do escola-->
  
 </section>
```

Comment: Sobre o botão das categorias, gostei que o código ficou menor, só vou pensar em mudar as cores do layout que como você ver:

Só os Botões do Clube e da Familia que tem uma alteração diferente.

`/* .buttonClub:hover, .buttonEscola:hover, .buttonInvestidor:hover, .buttonFamilia:hover, .buttonActive{ */
.buttonDefault:hover, .buttonActive{
 background: #e8c29c;
 border-top-color: #D2AA82;
 border-bottom-color: #D2AA82;
}

.buttonClub:hover, .buttonClubActive{
 border-left-color: #D2AA82;
}

.buttonFamilia:hover, .buttonFamiliaActive{
 border-right-color: #D2AA82;
}`

Comment: e na questão do botão ver mais, ficou bom também, só que o problema é que cada categoria vai ter um tamanho diferente.

porque cada plano vai ter suas informações diferentes e com quantidades diferentes ou seja, vai alterar o tamanho.

Comment: Isso é fácil de resolver...

Comment: Vc pode usar o método `.slide` do jquery em vez de adicionar uma classe.... o `.slide` desce a div do tamanho que ela tiver, não precisa fixar uma altura.

Comment: e na questão do .animate, esse era o principal, pq justo ele não ta funcionando em outros planos, somente no primeiro `if`.

Eu queria deixar pra ficar mais legal, quando clica no botão ver mais ai o scroll desce e sobe de acordo com o botão. Mas ele só está descendo, ele não sobe, e também só está funcionando no primeiro `if`. Fora que a animação também fica mais legal.

Comment: sério? como faço com o .slide ?

Comment: opa eu agradeço. Infelizmente javascript ainda não sei desenvolver, tenho dificuldades kkk

Comment: vlw :). o Site completo é esse: https://juarysantos.com/

ai falta essa page de planos que eu tava fazendo ia me deparei com esse erro e me travou kk

Comment: O slide não funciona nesse caso, mas nem precisava mesmo pq o transition do CSS já resolve. Veja agora como ficou, talvez precisa de algum ajuste para o seu site, mas aí vc testa e me fala.

Comment: Ficou ótimo, obrigado, só no mobile que ficou passando demais, mas o restante ficou ótimo, vou atualizar lá pra vc ver

Comment: coloquei aqui pra ficar mais fácil pra ver: https://juarysantos.com/price.html

Comment: o da "Escola" ficou excelente, só os outros passaram demais

Comment: Dá uma olhada agora. Só consegui fazer o scroll após a animação do CSS, isso porque quando a animação está sendo executada, o jQuery não consegue calcular a distância dos elementos ao topo.

Comment: ficou ótimo, muito obrigado :)

Answer (score 0):

A condição:

```
if ('#clublist' + id) {}
```

sempre será verdadeira. Por isso o erro diz que não existe o elemento `#clublist4`, por exemplo.

Tente:

```
if ($('#clublist' + id).length) {}
if ($('#escolalist' + id).length) {}
```

etc...

Em relação à dica de economizar linhas, acredito que não existe a necessidade de ter uma classe específica para cada categoria (`.planClub`, `.planEscola`, etc).